# MySQL: fetch a row and multiple related rows - possible?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, select

Let's say I have one table: "**cars**" with 3 fields: id, brand, cost.

There's a second table: "**models**" with 3 fields: id, brand, model_name.

Each "cars" row can have multiple related "models" rows.

Is it possible to do an sql-select whose output looks like this?

edit: I use PHP for the database querys

```
array(
  [0] => array(
     [id] => 1
     [brand] => mercedes
     [cost] => 1000
     [models] => array(
       [0] => array(
         [id] => 1
         [brand] => mercedes
         [model_name] => slk
       )
       [1] => array(
         [id] => 2
         [brand] => mercedes
         [model_name] => clk
       )
       [2] => array(
         [id] => 3
         [brand] => mercedes
         [model_name] => whatever
       )
     )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a foreign key relation to the models table, say `car_id`.  Then:

```
SELECT * FROM cars JOIN models ON car_id = models.id;
```

This will output something similar to what you are looking for.

Assuming you are using PHP, using the output:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM cars JOIN models ON car_id = models.id";
$r= @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $carstuff['id']=$row[id];
    $carstuff['brand']=$row[brand];
    $carstuff['cost']=$row[cost];
    $carstuff[$row['models']][]=$row['model_name'];
}

var_dump($carstuff);
```

Note, that the id, brand and cost are repeatedly overwritten, but that is okay because they are overwritten with the same information.  I'm not too sure about the cleanliness of the code, but that is the basic idea.

Comment: yes, but in this case i get on complete array for each model (complete means with all data from cars and that model), but i would like to have it all in one array

Comment: How are you accessing the database?  PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Query:**

```
SELECT c.ID, c.brand,c.cost, GROUP_CONCAT(model_name SEPARATOR '","')  as models
, GROUP_CONCAT(m.ID SEPARATOR ',')  as MID
, GROUP_CONCAT(m.brand SEPARATOR '","')  as mbrand
FROM cars c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN model m 
ON m.brand = c.brand
GROUP BY brand;
```

**Output:**

```
ID  BRAND       COST    MODELS            MID   MBRAND
1   audi        1000    m11","m22     4,5   audi","audi
1   mercedes    1200    m1","m2","m3      1,2,3 mercedes","mercedes","mercedes
```

Now in your php code you can process the MODEL,MID and MBrand
(By using [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php))

```
$modelArray = explode(" ,", $row["MODELS");
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c81ecd/6)